# boundary of the half-annulus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis

**Question**
Let C be the boundary of the half-annulus

a^2 < (x^2 + y^2) < b^2 and y>=0

in the x-y plane, traversed in the negative direction
what is

∫ (5e^(-7x^2) - y^3) dx + x^3 +cosh^2(5y) dy

**My attempt** 
∫c [(5e^(-7x^2) - y^3) dx + (x^3 + cosh^2(5y)) dy]

= -∫c' [(5e^(-7x^2) - y^3) dx + (x^3 + cosh^2(5y)) dy], where C' has positive orientation

= -∫∫ [(∂/∂x)(x^3 + cosh^2(5y)) - (∂/∂y)(5e^(-7x^2) - y^3)] dA, by Green's Theorem

= -∫∫ 3(x^2 + y^2) dA, over the interior of C (or C')

= -∫(θ = 0 to π) ∫(r = a to b) 3r^2 * (r dr dθ), converting to polar coordinates

= -π * (3/4)r^4 {for r = a to b}

= (3π/4)(a^4 - b^4)

Is this the correct method to answering this question? Can someone explain why green theorem works?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is correct; this problem was designed for an application of Green's theorem. If you are asking why Green's theorem applies here, the answer is: because both components of the vector field have continuous derivatives in the half-annulus  domain, including its boundary. If you are asking why Green's theorem is true, my answer is: because we have a proof (see a textbook or Wikipedia). If you want an "intuitive" reason why it's true, I think it's better to think of 2D divergence theorem first: the net amount of substance that flows across the boundary of a region is equal to the amount of substance that is produced inside the region. Green's theorem is like that, but with flow *along* the boundary instead of across it, and with vortices instead of sources/sinks inside the region. The [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) shows the equivalence of Green's theorem and 2D divergence theorem.